# Share background image between elements using CSS or TailwindCSS

Tags: css, background-image, background-attachment, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make something like this on Tailwind or pure css...

[image: Power Bar]

So basically we could share some background between elements with some css similar like this (we use this class on each element):

```css
.item {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

and this is the HTML, it shouldn't matter the amount of divs,  the important thing is to display the complete gradient scale...

```
            <div class="w-full mb-4 ">
                <div class="flex flex-row" >
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1" ></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1" ></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1"></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1"></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1"></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1"></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1"></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1"></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1"></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1"></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1"></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1"></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1"></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1"></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1"></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1"></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1"></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1"></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1"></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1"></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1"></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1"></div>
                    <div class="h-10 item mx-1 rounded-b-full rounded-t-full w-1"></div>                        
                </div>
            </div>
```

The problem is that "background-attachment: fixed" is relative to the viewport and not the container element.  So in order to see the full color scale I have to maximize the browser.

Is there any trick for this or any background-attachment that is relative to the container but not the viewport?

Comment: can you share the html code? you will have many element like the screenshot or less?

Comment: Yes I will have multiple divs with the "element" class. Inside a wrapper div.  I'm skipping details like margins, width and height of the divs, I'm more concerned about the background

Comment: the solution will depend on your html code, that's why you need to share you use case. We cannot give you a generic solution because there is no way to make `fixed` related to a container

Comment: HTML code added

Comment: Hi @TemaniAfif, I closed the duplicate question as you just pointed out. Do you have any idea about how to solve this?

Comment: a generic solution: no .. I can only give workaround or approximation for some specific use case but you didn't share any particular HTML structure, you simply added a *generic* html code without any CSS so I doubt you will get a clear answer unless you give more details about your use case with real code so people (and not only me) can help you.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  The only custom class is .item which code is at the beginning of this post. The other classes are TailwindCSS classes.

w-full = width:100%,
mb-4 = margin-bottom : 1rem;

Comment: I understand I have made a very specific question for this, that's why I asked something similar in the other post but like more generic or simpler.

I will be researching more on this. Thanks anyway